# Is there a way to use Dart Sass command line version with web pack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, sass-loader, dart-sass

From the [dart-sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) documentation we see that the dart-sass has a command-line version and is more performant.

I want to know if we can somehow use that command-line version with the existing webpack set up to speed up our build-time performance.

I can install dart libraries in the build machine. But is there any webpack plugin which can leverage that and use the machine dependencies to build sass rather than dart-sass npm?

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though the dart-sass team is working to support this case (see this [issue](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/248)). But the work isn't finished.

> But is there any webpack plugin which can leverage that and use the machine dependencies to build sass rather than dart-sass npm?

Not that I can find. However, it would be possible to create your own [loader](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/) which uses the dart executable (the source for [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/tree/master/src) is a good point of reference, and not very complicated). Since the dart cli takes options to read from stdin (`sass --stdin`), you should be able to pipe to the cli and pass back the output.

There might be other ways to accomplish your aim with a webpack extension, but using a loader seems the most straightforward in my view.

Is this faster than using the js api that `sass-loader` uses? Well, according to the [benchmarks](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/86b16f5500c9a53d248979890a0bc71cfc812315/perf.md), the advantage of the executable varies between 1.7 and 4.1 times faster (excluding the simplest case in which the executable runs 24 times faster, but is still sub-second execution for all cases). But there will be overhead for process generation, so you would have to measure to see what is faster in your case.